# Header files slow down the program

Tags: c++

My program have encountered a strange error: the header files slows the program down. I test the header file with empty code ( that is : `main() {}` ) and it takes 40s to run that empty code.

Header files .h

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <string>

#ifndef LZ_H
#define LZ_H

extern int e,i;
extern std::string dic[1000000];
void init();

#endif
```

Functions file .cpp

```
#include "lz.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

std::string dic[1000000];
int i=0;
int e=0;
std::string cstr(char c)                            
{  
    return std::string(1,c);  
}

void init()
{        
    for (e=0;e<=255;e++) dic[e]=cstr(e);   
        e=e-1;        
}
```

Test main file .cpp

```
#include "lz.h"  
void main() {}
```

Result: 40s.
I have never faced such strange error before.

Comment: Side note: What's with all those spaces before the end of lines? Also, could the long execution time be related to a million `std::string`s trying to construct?

Comment: Globals are default initialised. So that array gets filled with empty strings, whether you do anything with it or not. (Disclaimer: I may be wrong about the particular type of initialisation, but the same principle holds).

Comment: You should not include `"stdafx.h"` in your header file. Instead it should be the first file to be included in your source file.

Comment: Also, if you really want a "dictionary" you should look at [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Answer (score 13):

By putting a global declarations of one million strings in the .cpp file, you are forcing the compiler to put in the code to create one million string objects when the program starts. This is the reason for your slowdown.

As you are only using the first 256 elements of the array, change it to be of size 256.

Comment: Maybe. But when I run line by line with few codes in main(), the program slow in the end, not in the start. It extremely slow when I reach in '}'.

Comment: That is because all the one million strings must also be destructed, which takes considerable amounts of time as well.